# MFC CTaskDialog: modify position and height of dialogwindow

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dialog, position

Is there an easy way to modify the position of the dialogwindow? I want to have it on the right side of the screen with a fixed height and width. But the CTaskDialog class just offers to change the width of the window. Here some example code from msdn which I want to modify:

```
// TODO: Replace the strings below with the appropriate message,  
// main instruction, and dialog title
CString message("This is an important message to the user.");
CString mainInstruction("Important!\nPlease read!");
CString title("Alert Dialog");

CTaskDialog taskDialog(message, mainInstruction, title, 
    TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON | TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON );

// Setting new information to be able to reuse the dialog resource
taskDialog.SetWindowTitle(L"New title for the task dialog");
taskDialog.SetContent(L"New message to show the user.");
taskDialog.SetMainInstruction(L"Even more important!");
taskDialog.SetMainIcon(TD_ERROR_ICON);
taskDialog.SetDialogWidth(300);

// Add a footer
taskDialog.SetFooterText(L"Footer information for the dialog.");
taskDialog.SetFooterIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);

// Add expansion information
taskDialog.SetExpansionArea(L"Additional information\non two lines.",
    L"Click here for more information.",
    L"Click here to hide the extra information.");

// Change the options to show the expanded information by default. 
// It is necessary to retrieve the current options first. 
int options = taskDialog.GetOptions();
options |= TDF_EXPANDED_BY_DEFAULT;
taskDialog.SetOptions(options);

taskDialog.DoModal();
```

Comment: you can call MoveWindow on it, in CDialog::OnInitDialog()

Comment: When I do that, then only the position of the mainwindow will change. I have a onclickbutton event in that window that dynamically opens dialogboxes which are always centered. But I want them to be somewhere else. Maybe I missed something with the OnInitDialog()?